$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\big( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i \big) ^2\frac 1{n^2} $ and a related series.
Let $S_1 = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\big( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i \big) ^2\frac 1{n^2}  $
And $S_2 =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {(\ln n) ^{-2P}}{n^P + P^{-(\ln n )^ {\frac 1P} }} $
Consider the following statements :-
$A :S_1$ is convergent
$B: S_2 $ is convergent only for $P>1$
Discuss whether $A$ and $B$ are true or false.
I could show $S_2$ is convergent for $P>1$ by simply bounding above by $\frac 1{n^p}$
but couldn't show the "only" part.
For $S_1$ , I tried integration of polynomial and various test  but couldn't conclude anything.
How may I proceed ? Hints Please.

You use symbol $P$ in two different contexts.

Where does $p$ belong to? $(\Bbb R_+?\Bbb N?\dots)$

The harmonic number $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\ln n$, and the Bertrand series $\sum_{n\ge2}\frac1{n^\alpha\,(\ln n)^\beta}$ converges as soon as $\alpha>1$, hence so does $S_1$.
As for $S_2$, it converges if $p\ge1$ since $\sum_{n\ge2}\frac1{n(\ln n)^2}$ does, but it also converges if $q:=\frac1p>1$, because then, for $n$ large enough,
$p^{-(\ln n)^{1/p}}=e^{(\ln q)(\ln n)^q}>e^{2\ln n}$ (for instance).

For $S_1$, use the fact that for (some) $0<\delta<1$, there exists an integer $N$
$$\frac{(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})^2}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^{1+\delta}}$$
for any $n\geq N$.
Hint. The growth rate of $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ is the same as $\ln n$, their difference is bounded by a constant. (In fact, there is a closed form of this sum in terms of $\pi$).
For $S_2$, I don't think the statement is true. Try $P=1/e$

Ah, I wrote an answer similar to this, since I was after, I will delete mine
